# Join on multiple columns with mapping table

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I kinda need help for this one. I have customer table and mapping table. I need to join the tables. The scenario are like this:

Table 1 (customer):

```
uid  job  level  status  
1    64   68     75
2    65   69     75
3    66   68     76
```

Table 2 (mapping_table):

```
groupid  lookup_id  lookup_desc
1               64  biker                
1               65  stuntman                
1               66  driver  
2               68  low         
2               69  high         
3               75  individu         
3               76  corporate
```

Query:

```
select
      uid,b.lookup_desc job,
      c.lookup_desc level,
      d.lookup_desc status
from 
      customer a
left join mapping_table b on a.job = b.lookup_id
left join mapping_table c on a.job = c.lookup_id
left join mapping_table d on a.job = d.lookup_id
```

I know this query can be run. but i want make it **simpler/faster** or maybe u have any suggestion with my queries? or that query are the best approach (triple left join)?

I working on Hiveql.

Any helps will be appreciate ;)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you don't want the query to repeat the job three times, so I think you mean:

```
select c.uid, j.lookup_desc as job,
       l.lookup_desc as level,
       s.lookup_desc as status
from customer c left join
     mapping_table j
     on c.job = j.lookup_id left join
     mapping_table l
     on c.level= l.lookup_id left join
     mapping_table s
     on c.status= s.lookup_id;
```

The other change I made is to use meaningful table aliases -- which affects the clarity of the code, but not performance.

Otherwise, your code is fine.

In most databases, you would want an index on `mapping_table(lookup_id, lookup_desc)`.  However, I don't think such an index would help in Hive.

Answer (score 0):

To make this faster, the only thing I would add (from your example) is to make there is an index on **customer.job** and **mapping_table.lookup_id**